# How to use an HTML element to resize one's browser window?

Tags: html, css, browser, webkit, responsive-design

I put a handle in the bottom right corner of [my website](http://www.designbits.de) that users can grab and drag to the left in order to observe how the design adapts to different browser window sizes ("Responsive Design").

So I added this to my HTML:

```
<a id="drag-me" title="Drag me to the left"></a>
```

The `title` attribute causes a little tooltip to pop up which is nice.

However, some users don't get the idea and try to grab the red `anchor` element itself rather than the bottom right corner of their browser window.

Is there any way to improve this?

Thanks for any ideas...

Comment: Honestly I am a web developer and the first thing I thought was grab the red thing. Lose it entirely and explain the concept another way. When a browser is maximized (which mine always is unless I am testing) you can't see the resize handle anyway, which makes it that much more confusing. If you really need to have it point the arrow to the corner, not out into the screen and use a CSS pop up to explain explicitly what you intend the user to do.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You are absolutely right. I just changed my design. "Zieh mich" is German for "drag me", so my audience will hopefully get the idea now. I also added a tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.resizeTo(width,height)
```

use `self.resizeTo()` to resize own window

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_resizeto.asp

Answer (score 0):

You would have to you the window.resizeTo() method in javascript to resize the window. Unfortunately, some browsers prevent it, including chrome:

Answer (score 0):

use position fixed; bottom:0; right:0 in css,
so every time able to see your handler element on current browser screen